Why doesn't my one-to-many ip6gre tunnel work?
As seen in this question Linux allows a point-to-multipoint GRE tunnel interface by leaving the tunnel's remote address blank and then using ip neigh to configure the remote address based on the address used by the packet being tunneled.
This works perfectly with a type gre tunnel over IPv4:
ip link add dev test type gre local X.X.X.X noseq nocsum key XXXXXXXXXX
ip link set test up
ip addr add 192.168.168.1/24 dev test
ping 192.168.168.2 # nothing received on receiver
ip neigh replace 192.168.168.2 lladdr Y.Y.Y.Y nud permanent dev test
ping 192.168.168.2 # encapsulated packets received on receiver
ip route add 192.168.169.0/24 via 192.168.168.2
ping 192.168.169.1 # encapsulated packets received on receiver
# interface gets a link-local address by default
ip -6 neigh add fe80::2 lladdr Y.Y.Y.Y dev test
ping fe80::2%test # encapsulated packets received on receiver
ip link del test

The same does not work over IPv6:
ip link add dev test type ip6gre local 2XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::1 noseq nocsum key XXXXXXXXXX
ip link set test up
ip addr add 192.168.168.1/24 dev test
ip neigh add 192.168.168.2 lladdr 2Y:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY nud permanent dev test
ping 192.168.168.2 # no packets transmitted, no errors displayed
ip -6 neigh add fe80::2 lladdr 2Y:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY nud permanent dev test
ping fe80::2%test # no packets transmitted, no errors displayed

Note the ip neigh command expects an IPv6 lladdr in MAC-address-like format. ip neigh show shows the correct address in IPv6 format, confirming it was accepted.
I also tried 55:55:55:55:55:55:55:55:55:55:55:55:55:55:55:55 in case of byte ordering issues. At this point I am only trying to get the local system to transmit a packet, not concerned about establishing end-to-end communication.
If the tunnel interface is created with the remote 2Y:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY option then it works, but it's one-to-one.
I can ping the remote address and get a response.
Packets that are not transmitted are reported as both "errors" and "dropped", but not "carrier" as they would be if the neighbour was missing from the neighbour table.
ip -s -s link show test
106: test@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1444 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/gre6 2XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::1 brd :: permaddr XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::
    RX:  bytes packets errors dropped  missed   mcast           
             0       0      0       0       0       0 
    RX errors:  length    crc   frame    fifo overrun
                     0      0       0       0       0 
    TX:  bytes packets errors dropped carrier collsns           
             0       0     16      16       0       0 
    TX errors: aborted   fifo  window heartbt transns
                     0      0       0       0       0 


This is due to a bug in Linux. In ip6gre_tunnel_xmit one of the first checks called is ip6_tnl_xmit_ctl to validate the source and destination address. However, it only validates the source and destination address configured on the tunnel itself, without doing a neighbour lookup first. Since :: isn't a valid destination, it concludes it can only receive packets but not send them, which would be true if the neighbour table wasn't going to set a correct destination.
IPv4 gre interfaces don't have this bug.
ip6tnl interfaces don't have this bug, but they have a different bug which causes them to use completely wrong destination addresses, so ip6tnl is unusable in one-to-many mode as well.
